Add data event to Android
Could I insert data to PostgreSQL and get insert data event to Android? I know Firebase can do that but I am more familiar to Postgres.

Reminder How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? Assuming you are aware of JDBC vs Web Service for Android one possible flow is this answer to offline/online sync
